# SQL INSERT INTO with empty foreign table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 values and a foreign table.

Tbl_Person

```
ID    int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
CarID int REFERENCES Tbl_Car(ID)
Name  nvarchar(20)
```

Tbl_Car

```
ID    int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
Color nvarchar(30)
```

I now want to create a new `Person` with a new `Car` without caring about the `Car` table, sort of like this:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Person (Car, Name) 
VALUES ('dont know what goes here', 'Timmy')
```

I'm not sure what to put inside the `Car` column since I just want it to exist but not care about its values just yet.

I'm sure its quite easy to find online but I have no idea how to Google for this particular problem.

Comment: Not sure what you want here.  Is "Timmy" a color, or something else?

Comment: Whops, that should've been Car, Name lol

Comment: Where is the field `Car` defined?

Comment: You can't insert a row and "not care about its values". You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to capture the identity of a row after it's been inserted, for use in another row, or you can leave the column `NULL`.

Comment: I think you want `INSERT INTO Tbl_Person (CarID, Name) VALUES (NULL, N'Timmy');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter the logical model to denormalize 'CarID' (remove it from 'Persons' table) and create a new table to store persons' cars called 'Person_Cars'.  This avoids inserting `NULL` values into the model when the car is unknown. Depending on which table constraints are applied it also could allow for persons to have more than 1 car.  Also, prefixing tables with 'tbl_' is not necessary.  Also, both Persons and Cars seem likely to benefit from a unique constraint on the `NVARCHAR` column(s).

Persons

```
ID          int not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
Name        nvarchar(20) unique not null
```

Cars

```
ID          int not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
Car         nvarchar(30) unique not null
```

Person_Cars

```
ID          int not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
PersonID    int not null REFERENCES Persons(ID)
CarID       int not null REFERENCES Cars(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Car (
ID    int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Color nvarchar(30));

CREATE TABLE Tbl_Person (
ID    int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
CarID int REFERENCES Tbl_Car(ID),
Name  nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO Tbl_Person (CarID, Name) VALUES (NULL, 'Timmy');
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f6b0d2a8130b6970005ef0ba5e357f3)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a logical operation. You can not just give the car an ID but it must have a name.

change `Tbl_Car` to :

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Car (
ID    int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
CarName  nvarchar(30),
Color nvarchar(30));
```

To enter the `Tbl_Person` table, you must know the name of the person's car :

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Person VALUES(CarID,Name)
SELECT ID,'Timmy'
FROM Tbl_Car 
WHERE CarName = 'BMW'
```